# linux-perf-5.4 for amd64

Tags: pi-4, 64-bit

My raspi4/8GB is running the 64bit version of Raspberry Pi OS. The linux kernel is 5.4, but perf is only linux-perf-4.19. There seems to be no matching perf version. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `linux-perf-5.9` from [`buster-backports`](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/linux-perf).

[How to install Debian packages on Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107472/33476). Don't forget to replace `buster` with `buster-backports`.

You'll have to call `perf_5.9` instead of just `perf`, or modify the `perf` wrapper script to use `perf_5.9` instead of `perf_5.4`.